# AWS Lambda and ECS Tasks - what is the best way to orchestrate?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-ecs, serverless, amazon-vpc

I'm creating my application with the as much serverless as possible premise.

Long story short, 2 services cannot be implemented as lambda functions, hence I bet on ECS tasks with EC2 autoscaling groups, due to GPU requirements, etc.

After doing my homework on the Lambda + VPC resources lesson I was shocked there's no easy and pleasant way to expose VPC services extension of AWS services. So the official approach stands for incorporating a lambda function into a VPC plus establishing a NAT gateway/instance or VPC endpoints in order to reach the internet and AWS services. Moreover, I can read this is not recommended and should be treated as the final solution. It slows down lambda and increases cold starts.

Generally, I need access to the internet and reach other AWS services from the lambda, which must make requests to ECS tasks. Those tasks are crucial contributors to my flow I'd like them to be easily callable from lambda functions. I'm not sure if VPC lambdas would make sense if I need to pay for NAT, which is comparatively expensive. Maybe I missed something.

Is it possible to avoid incorporating lambdas into VPC and still be able to call ECS services? If not, what is the best way to cuts costs related to NAT?

I'd appreciate any form of help.

Comment: Are your ECS tasks located in a private subnet of a VPC? It is not mentioned anywhere. So I guess they are public?

Comment: They are located in the private subnet. I don't want them to be accessible from the outside - no authorization, etc.